# Excel VBA 2 Sheets compare and fill if empty

Tags: excel, vba

I got 2 Sheets each with a table.
The tables on those sheets have the same format, same length etc.
Row 1 is the days of the month and column A are the employees.

Now I want to compare those two sheets. Sheet1 is the main, if one cell is empty I would like to check if there is data in Sheet2 same cell. If yes, copy it into Sheet1. If no, leave empty.

Is this possible?

VLOOKUP semms like the simple solution but I cant figure out how to do it with 2 criterias (Name and Date)

For filling empty cell i got this code but dont know if thats the best method.

```
Sub Fill_empty_cell()

Set MR = Range("C3:X600")
For Each cell In MR

If IsEmpty(cell.Value) = True Then

   cell.Value = "VLOOKUP????"   
End If
Next
End Sub
```

Thanks for any help!
Daniel

Comment: Was here a helpful answer for you? If yes, please mark it as accepted and upvote it...

Comment: I cant upvote it, because I need 15 reputation. But I promise as soon as I get 15 reputation I will come back to upvote it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub Fill_empty_cell()

    Dim sheet1 As Worksheet
    Dim sheet2 As Worksheet

    Dim rangeToCheck As Range

    Set sheet1 = Sheets("Test1")
    Set sheet2 = Sheets("Test2")
    Set rangeToCheck = sheet1.Range("A2:D30")

    For Each cellToCheck In rangeToCheck

        If IsEmpty(cellToCheck.Value) = True Then

           cellToCheck.Value = sheet2.Cells(cellToCheck.Row, cellToCheck.Column).Value
   
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Here you can set a Range by String...

Comment: Thank you so much! it works like a charm. It takes quite a while when the range is C3:X400 in my case but works perfectly. 
I am very grateful!

Comment: You're welcome ;)... about performance: this is a problem of VBA, if you need something which runs really faster, you can use python and the library openpyxl or write a PowerShell (using win32com interface) script instead.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible the easiest way would be using For loops and defining all cells in the range by number (cells(x,y)) and use an if statements to compare those for the different sheets (eg. sheet1.cells(x,y) to sheet2.cells.(x,y))

The if checks if its empty if sheet2 is empty if will stay empty but if somethings is their it will be put in sheet 1

```
Sub Fill_empty_cell()

Dim x As Long
Dim y As Long

x = 3
y = 3

For x = 3 To 21 'this is the column number of x I think please check
    For y = 3 To 300
        If ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(y, x) = "" Then
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(y, x) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Cells(y, x)
        End If
    Next y
Next x

End Sub
```